# Convert reports generated in PHP/MySQL/HTML to PDF format on a Mac

Tags: php, mysql, macos, pdf-generation

I'm working on some pages that combine html, php, and mysql to create reports from a mysql database. I'd like to be able to create a button to convert these reports to PDF files for the user to download. Any idea of how to approach this (on a Mac, I might add)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've used [PDFlib](http://pdflib.com) a lot in my projects. You can build PDFs from the ground up programmatically, or use a template PDF and add new things on top of that. The downside is that it's a commercial library, and the licensing cost is fairly steep.

Answer (score 1):

You can use libraries to allow you to create pdf files directly on your server  side. The most recommended one for such use is [tcpdf](http://www.tcpdf.org/).  This will allow you to custom format your reposrt and then convert them to pdf on the fly.

Answer (score 1):

We use [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for some of our reports. It's pretty simple PHP syntax, not hard to figure out, but it is a tad limited. I've heard good things about [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/) as well, which seems to have a few more features and is about as easy to use.

Unfortunately, you probably won't find much more than that using just PHP. You could generate XML/XDP files to populate a pre-made PDF file (we do this on one such report), but it introduces extra steps and large possibilities for glitches.